# How to use sh script to send hex data to /dev/ttyUSB0?

Tags: shell, hex, ttyusb, ash

I'm working with a paired down embedded Linux installation that does not support bash, only sh across a ssh terminal.  I need to send hex data to a connected USB device `/dev/ttyUSB0`.  I'm able to do this easily enough with bash (on a desktop installation of Ubuntu 18.04) using `echo -en '\x01\x02\x03' > /dev/ttyUSB0`, but it seems that the backslash escapes are not supported by sh.  Is there another relatively easy (or even not-so-easy) way to do this with sh?

Unfortunately, `$SHELL --version` is not returning anything.  Kernel version is 4.1.0.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas, argh, right, of course

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I used my Ubuntu desktop to create binary files.

```
echo -en '\x01\x02\x03' > binary.file
```

Then, after copying the binary file to my system running ash shell, I cat that file in my script to the USB.

```
cat binary.file > /dev/ttyUSB0
```

It'd be nice if there were a better way to do this, without the intermediary step of creating a set of binary files, but this'll work for now.

Answer (score 1):

This is one of the reasons [why printf is better than echo](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803/why-is-printf-better-than-echo). Implementations of `echo` vary in if and how they support options and backslash-escapes, but all versions of `printf` should support backslash-escapes.

The only catch is that only octal escapes, like `\001` are standard, so `\x01` might not be available everywhere even with `printf`. You could start by trying `printf "\x01"` though.

If that doesn't work, you'll have to switch to octal. Either do the conversion off-line with any programmer's calculator, or use something like `printf "%o\n" "0x61"` to convert or use something like this to batch-convert your string:

```
echo 'foo\x01\x61' | perl -pe 's/\\x([0-9a-fA-F]{2})/sprintf("\\%03o", hex($1))/ge'
```

(it should give `foo\001\141`)

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately my target (running ash shell) doesn't support perl.

Comment: @JimFell, mostly I meant to do the hex-octal conversion offline

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing slash `/` and backslash `\`.

Escaping is done with backslash:

```
echo -en '\x01\x02\x03' > /dev/ttyUSB0
```

Comment: Kudos for catching the typo, but sh echo still doesn't support the backslash escaping.

Comment: Any ideas why I have to echo twice before the device actually accepts the hex being sent?